# 240V outlet (4 prong) reads 240V between live and neutral - dryer

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, circuit-breaker, 240v

Dryer used to work fine until one day it stopped powering up.
In checking the outlet, here are the findings (A - Live1, B - Live2, C - Neutral, D - Ground):

AB - 240V as expected

AC - 240V (should be 120)

BC - 0?

AD - 120V

BD - 0V

CD - 120V

I'm  stumped as to how it would work before since nothing changed..

Comment: What do you get for D ground?

Comment: AD 120V, BD 0V, CD 120V

Comment: Some how B or C is broken and connected to each other.   Turn off the breaker and start checking from the receptacle to breaker.  Really start at the dryer connections back.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are testing the outlet with the drier unplugged, I would suspect a combination of two factors.

1. Someone tapped a 120V load off the drier circuit (or even just tapped it's neutral for a 120V load that is fed from another circuit........).
2. The neutral wire is broken.

When a neutral wire breaks, if there is a load conencted then the load will pull the neutral up to line voltage.

Testing voltages relative to ground should confirm whether or not this is the case.

Comment: The 120V load on the dryer outlet *probably is the dryer*.  It has internal 120V devices- in fact the whole dryer except for the heating element. Because https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=744 ... but yeah, I agree with your Lost Neutral assessment and I think you have the answer covered.

Comment: I would expect someone testing a socket to have unplugged the load from that socket first, which is why I suspected a tapped off load rather than the drier itself.